# Apache Camel jms inOut bean binding return type

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

Using apache camel jms queue synchrons way. inOut pattern.
On consumer side define routeBuilder:

```
 context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
     @Override
     public void configure() {
         JacksonDataFormat request = new JacksonDataFormat(Request.class);
         JacksonDataFormat response = new JacksonDataFormat(Response.class);
         from(queueName)
             .unmarshal(request)
             .bean(MessageHandler.class, "handle");
             .marshal(response);
     }
 });
```

and here is a handlig bean example:

```
public class MessageHandler {
    @Handler
    public Response handle(final Request request) {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Its not working for me.

If im defining simple route builder without Camel json serialization/deserealisation like this:

```
public class MessageHandler {
    @Handler
    public String handle(final String request) {
        return "some json";
    }
}
```

its working. 
Question - is possible to define handler with a strong typisation, istead of plain strings(json or whatever)

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. Which Camel version you are using? Your example is working for me as expected with `2.21.1`, I have just removed semicolon after `.bean(MessageHandler.class, "handle")`, because I assume it is copy-paste mistake and it worked well, the method `handle` was invoked without errors.

Comment: Hi Bedla! Sure, semicolon is copy/paste issue... My Camel version is 2.21.0, which should be quite fine.